# How can I put a constraint on the output signal from deconvolution using deconvwnr or other deconvolution methods?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, deconvolution

I want to deconvolve a signal with a point spread function to retrieve a "ground truth" signal. I know that the ground truth is roughly Gaussian and should be 7x7 pixels.

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v80WS.jpg)

This works when I do deconvolution with the raw signal. However, when I alter the signal with interpolation then try to deconvolve I get this weird periodic semi-gaussian signal that is the same length as the point spread function (47 pixels).

[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2sFe.jpg)

Is it possible to restrict the size of the output to be a 7x7 image? Or to constrain it so that the output has a Gaussian spread?
Here is the code. The variables are in the dropbox link:

```
    deconvwnr(temp,sptint,0)
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2ajzo52el6gy57/answers.mat?dl=0

Edit: If Weiner filter deconvolution can't do it, is there any deconvolution that can? Or alternatively, is there some mathematical way to restore the 7x7 Gaussian signal using what I have?

edit 2: I have attached a comma separated sheet: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7tmrpsfbhaxixcj/Alexa%20Fluor%20647.csv?dl=0

To generate the Gaussian I do

```
w=116.4736
px=106.6667
truth  = fspecial('gaussian',7,w/px);
```

Then to generate sptint I do

```
load 'Alexa Fluor 647.csv';
spt = Alexa_Fluor_647(:,3);
sptint=interp1(300:900,spt,600:5:800);
```

Then to generate temp I do

```
sptimg = conv2(truth,spt');
sptimg(:,end-(3-1):end)=[];
sptimg(:,1:3)=[];
sptimg2 = interp1(300:900,sptimg',600:5:800)';
temp=zeros(7,47)
temp(:,4:44)=sptimg2(:,:,1);
```

Comment: the output of a filtered image can't be smaller than the original image. It is like trying to take an image of a car, smeared along the road due to long exposure, then try to get the original car size. You cannot do it with deburring.

Comment: I see. That is true. But knowing that the original image is of a car, and knowing the car size (I know the sigma of the Gaussian) couldn't you constrain it so that the pixel intensity values outside the known car size are zero if you are doing an iterative deconvolution method?

Comment: can you add the code that you used to generate both outputs?

Comment: @bla I have added the code and a csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A weighted average can be considered.
Using a sliding window, you move a 7 by 7 window from left to right of temp, mulitpy the numbers by a weight (sptint for that window) and add the result iteratively.

```
startAvg = 1:47-6;
avg = zeros(7);
for ii = 1:length(startAvg)
    avg = avg + temp(:,startAvg(ii):startAvg(ii)+6)*sptint(ii);
end
avg = avg/ii
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think this is a good approach. When I do 

`conv2(sptint,avg)`

 the answer doesn't quite match temp. I think this is close, and I will play with it a bit and accept your answer and give bounty once I figure it out.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out. The pattern is close to correct, but the values are off by some orders of magnitude. I guess some normalization factor is needed. I don't really understand the logic for this either. Does this method have a name?